# Make trasparent (traslucent) background (icecream sandwich)

Tags: android, android-activity, background

On my app i've some activity with traslucent background
i make it with this code on activity:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
```

and this code on manifest

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
```

This work on all device that i have tested, but in some device i've a black bacground
This device are:
Sony xperia ray
samsung galaxy s duos
htc c

All this device have iceCream Sandwich

i have no problema on device with jb and gingerbrand
how can i set the traslucent background?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is [WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND). This constant was deprecated in Ice Cream Sandwich.

Comment: uhm but why deprecated it on ics and not on jb?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `styles.xml`

```
<style name="EmptyActivity">
 <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
<item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:colorForeground">#000</item>
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item> 
 <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item> 
 <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>
```

I'm assuming that in ICS, the `dim` is what's causing the `black screen`. I've disabled it in the code, so hopefully it should work.